# How to design css box as below image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is there any possibility to do like below image using CSS?
I don't have any idea where to start. Is it achieved by border-radius property?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are a few online tools to generate this kind of stuff, for example:

[CSS Tooltip Generator](http://www.cssportal.com/css-tooltip-generator/)

Example code (HTML):

```
<div style='padding:50px'>
  <a class="tooltips" href="#">CSS Tooltips
    <span>Tooltip</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Example code (CSS):

```
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width:140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```